# Helm Chart - How to validate the chart without installing?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using the following command to install the Helm chart

```
helm upgrade myRelease azureacr/chart --namespace calculator --install --set replicaCount=4 --set image.repository=my.azurecr.io --set canary=false --wait --timeout 45s
```

it works perfectly fine.

However, I want to (re)view the generated chart before installing it? The below command just prints the template and I don't know how to pass the parameters to it

```
helm template myRelease
```

In other words, I know that the value of "c" is 2 for the below code

```
var a = 1, b = 1, c = a +b
```

In the same way, is there a way to get the final chart by applying the required parameters?

Comment: `helm template` takes all the same `--set` and `-f` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using --dry-run command in helm install something like this

`helm upgrade myRelease azureacr/chart --namespace calculator --install --set replicaCount=4 --set image.repository=my.azurecr.io --set canary=false --wait --timeout 45s --dry-run --debug`

It's a great way to have the server render your templates, then return the resulting manifest file.